# NSObjectInaccessibleException - Deletando todos os objetos de uma entity - NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Tenho uma função responsável por deletar todos os itens de uma entidade:

```
func removeItens() {
    if let managedContext = managedObjectContext {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entidade", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity
        fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false

        var error: NSError?
        var resultados = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)

        for resultado in resultados as [NSManagedObject] {
            managedContext.deleteObject(resultado)
        }

        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            println("could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

A minha aplicação consiste de uma TabBar com 3 telas:

Na primeira tab, eu possuo uma listagem de cidades, e ao seleciona o usuário é enviado para uma tela de listagem de produtos, no qual ele pode "marcar" os produtos.

A segunda tab possui uma tela que mostra a listagem destes produtos marcados.

Porém, eu preciso deletar todos os objetos desta entidade sempre que o usuário selecionar uma cidade diferente ou quando ele inicia a aplicação depois de terminada.

Para o primeiro caso, eu chamo a função no "prepareForSegue" quando o usuário seleciona uma cidade, e funciona perfeitamente.

O problema surge quando eu tento executar no segundo caso. Se eu tento chamar esta função no "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" do AppDelegate ou no "viewDidLoad" da primeira tab, o banco é corrompido, e eu recebo a seguinte mensagem quando eu tento entrar na segunda tab:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xd000000000140000 ''**

Porém, se eu retiro a função do "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" ou do "viewDidLoad" da primeira tab, a aplicação funciona perfeitamente.

**==Atualizado==**

Observando com mais atenção, o erro está ocorrendo na segunda tab (a de listagem de produtos).

Eu possuo uma variável no qual eu utilizo para manter atualizado os itens da tabela (caso o usuário marque algum produto).

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entidade", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nome", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: managedContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "nome",
        cacheName: "Entidade")

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

E o erro está ocorrendo exatamente nesta linha:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()

    var error: NSError?
    if !fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) { // <----- Esta
        fatalCoreDataError(error)
    }
}
```

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

O problema estava inteiramente na segunda tab.

A resposta para o problema foi remover a variável:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    .
    .
    .
}()
```

Agora o "viewDidLoad" da segunda tab ficou da seguinte forma (Foi removido o fetch):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
}
```

Foi adicionado a seguinte variável:

```
var entidades = [Entidade]()
```

E adicionados os seguintes métodos:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    fetchLog()
}
```

E

```
func fetchLog() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entidade")

    var error: NSError? = nil

    if let results = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as? [Entidade] {
        self.entidades = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Com estas alterações, eu posso finalmente remover os itens quando a aplicação é iniciada, colocando o seguinte código na tela de listagem de cidades:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    appDelegate.removeItens()
}
```

Ou optar por chamar o método "removeItens()" no AppDelegate quando a aplicação inicia ou termina.

Se alguém precisar, posso postar o código fonte inteiro das telas.

**Atualizado**

Descobri o que de fato aconteceu, eu tenho um método no AppDelegate no qual é responsável por atualizar o "badgeValue" da tab de listagem, sempre que um usuário marca um produto.

Ele estava da seguinte forma (e era chamado cada vez que ocorria alguma alteração no managedObjectContext):

```
func atualizaUI() {
    let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController

    if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
        let navigationController = tabBarViewControllers[3] as UINavigationController
        let listaViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as ListaViewController
        listaViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext // <--- Aqui está o problema

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entidade")
        if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) {
            navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = String(fetchResults.count)
        }
    }
}
```

Eu não posso setar o managedObjectContext para uma tela desta forma, eu preciso atribuí-lo uma única vez no "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions", sendo assim, eu consegui manter o código anterior para poder usufruir do NSFetchedResultsController